ImageMagick Pango Creates Visible Edge Artifacts on Text
Pango creates very visible edge artifacts (chromatic aberrations) compared to caption. Any way to get rid of those artifacts? Tried to change hinting for pango, but it didn't change anything.
ImageMagick version 7.1.1-32
I do need to use pango and not other method.
Thanks!
magick -background gray -font Arial -fill rgb(200,210,220) -pointsize 20 pango:"TEXT" -trim +repage pango.png

magick -background gray -font Arial -fill rgb(200,210,220) -pointsize 27 caption:"TEXT" -trim +repage caption.png



Zoomed in comparison between caption and pango outputs

